# Reading two external owl files in a servlet page and manipulating results

Tags: java, nlp, sparql, rdf, jena

I am using an owl file as an input and doing a SPARQL query in a servlet page.

```
Model modelFile = FileManager.get().loadModel
("C:\\Users\\admin\\IdeaProjects\\SampleWebProject\\src\\main\\java
\\OWLComparison\\CVDetails.rdf");

String query =
                "PREFIX rdf: <http://www.w3.org/1999/02/22-rdf-syntax-ns#>" +
                        "PREFIX owl: <http://www.w3.org/2002/07/owl#> " +
                        "PREFIX rdfs: <http://www.w3.org/2000/01/rdf-schema#> " +
                        "PREFIX ns0: <http://www.Jobsurveillance.com/CV#> " +
                        "SELECT (str(?object) as ?label) " +
                        "(str(?object2) as ?label2) " +
                        "(str (?phoneNumobj) as ?label3) " +
                        "(str (?degreeobj) as ?label4) " +
                        "(str (?jobcatObj) as ?label5) WHERE { " +
                        " ?person ns0:Full_Name ?object ." +
                        " ?person ns0:Email_Id ?object2 ." +
                        " ?person ns0:Phone_Number ?phoneNumobj ." +
                        " ?person ns0:Degree ?degreeobj ." +
                        " ?person ns0:Job_Category ?jobcatObj ." +
                        " filter(regex(?jobcatObj, \"" + jobCatname + "\"))" +
                        "}";
```

In the above code I use a single input file to do a query manipulation. Now I would like to input a another owl file and do query using both files. Could anyone help me out in getting this done? Thanks in advance!

Comment: seriously, I'll never understand why people programming in Java are not using the Javadoc ... `Model::add`, or `Model::union`, or `RDFDataMgr.read`, or ...  - dozens of options, all mentioned in the Javadoc and/or Jena Documentation

Comment: I don't understand your answer. Can u pls elaborate on how to do?

Comment: As of now, I am using both datasets inside one file and doing a query selection. But actually I have to read two files and write 1 query which queries into both files and give me the required output.

Comment: And what's wrong with the solutions I told you? what about adding the data from the second file to the existing model? what about building a union model out of two models?

Comment: I can possibly use a UNION. But when I do the query execution how am i supposed to pass both the models. This is my code atm
`Model modelFile = FileManager.get().loadModel
                ("..../CVDetails.rdf");` and then during query execution 
`QueryExecution qexec = QueryExecutionFactory.create(query, modelFile);`